# is there a dll for tls that can run on winows?

Tags: windows, dll, tls, tcl

I have an exe that will look for a file on the server, and download the latest exe. All this is implemented in tcl on a linux machine. Since this communication is secure, I have used http and tls libraries of tcl. 
Now I have to run the same exe on a windows machine. So I have changed the runtime environment( when creating an exe) to windows ,inorder for the exe to work. 
But TLS library of tcl  has a .so file and that .so file gives an error saying "cannot execute libtls.so"
I know I have to create a dll file inorder fr the tls to run, My questions are:

a) Are there dll for tls library that can run on windows(for tcl)?

b) Is there a simpler way to create a dll for a tcl code/package ?
I have reffered this blog (https://www.patthoyts.tk/tclkit/building-basekits.html) but I found it a little complex.

Comment: perhaps the answer to your question is in this FAQ? http://www.tcl.tk/faq/tclwin.htm#sec-12-6

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried using twapi, but the dll that comes with twapi gives an error. It shows: 

couldn't read file "C:/users/.../twapi.tcl" : no such file or directory found while executing :source [file join [twapi::Twapi_GetInstallDir]twai.tcl]". 

I think this error is generated from the base dll that comes with the package